# Use \r on a String with multiple \n

Tags: python, stdout, sys

I have a String with multiple \n in it to get it in a square form f.ex. for a matrix, a map etc.

If I want to override this with

`sys.stdout.write("\r %s" % TheString)
 sys.stdout.flush()`

it jumps to the beginning of the last row, overrides it and prints the new string underneath.
But I want it to jump all the way up to the first row and override the entire output.
I tried it with multiple \r (times number of rows) but it didn't work. Is there an other possibility?

Thanks!

Comment: Only if you go the extra mile and take over the whole screen, e.g., with [`ncurses`](http://php.net/manual/book.ncurses.php). Otherwise you’re always confined to the last line, i.e., the line that is currently getting printed.

Comment: What would you consider "the first row" exactly? First line of output of your script?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke yes if I output 

***** \n
***** \n
***** \n
***** \n

I would like to jump to the first row of * and override all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC it's not easily possible as pointed by @Boldewyn  but you may clear the screen from the previous outputs before issuing a new `sys.stdout.write` using `os.system("clear")` (in UNIX-like systems):

```
import os
import sys

sys.stdout.write("This")
sys.stdout.write("Will")
sys.stdout.write("Not")
sys.stdout.write("Show")

# After this command all output before will be cleared
os.system("clear")
sys.stdout.write("\r %s" % "Blablablabla")
```